# How do I use values to create a stacked bargraph?

Tags: ggplot2

so I created three dataframes in R using the count function

```
scan_count_AB <- count(Hive_AB$Has_been_scanned == 1)
scan_count_C <- count(Hive_C$Has_been_scanned == 1)
scan_count_D <- count(Hive_D$Has_been_scanned == 1)

> scan_count_AB
      x freq
1 FALSE 1403
2  TRUE  627

> scan_count_C
      x freq
1 FALSE  167
2  TRUE  846

> scan_count_D
      x freq
1 FALSE  135
2  TRUE  880
```

Now I want to create three bargraphs that look like this

[image: Stacked bargraph]

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a `ggplot2`/`tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
# your data 
scan_count_AB <- data.frame(x= c(T, F), freq = c(1403, 627))
scan_count_C <- data.frame(x= c(T, F), freq = c(167, 846))
scan_count_D <- data.frame(x= c(T, F), freq = c(135, 880))
# and the plot
list(AB=scan_count_AB, C=scan_count_C, D=scan_count_D) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(perc = freq/(sum(freq))) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = c(T,F), labels=c("HNBS", "HBS"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(id, perc, fill = factor(x))) + 
   geom_col() +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
   scale_fill_discrete("") + 
   theme_bw() + 
   theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. So far it works, yet i get a small warning in Line 7. It says:" missing argument to function call" And my graph does not go up to a 100% on the "y-axis"

Comment: Install the `scales` package as well

Comment: Thank you, yet it is still the same Graph - https://imgur.com/a/i90JrXZ

Comment: library("ggpubr")
library(FSA)
library("readxl")  
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(agricolae)
library(Rmisc)
library(dplyr)
library(multcompView)
library(rlist)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)   -  This is all the librarys I am using

Comment: Of course.`list(AB=scan_count_AB, C=scan_count_C, D=scan_count_D) %>% bind_rows(.id = "id") %>% head
  id     x freq
1 AB FALSE 1403
2 AB  TRUE  627
3  C FALSE  167
4  C  TRUE  846
5  D FALSE  135
6  D  TRUE  880`

Comment: Yes, I just copy pasted your code. The Problem seems to happen here `ggplot(aes(id, perc, fill = factor(x, )))` - missing argument to function call

Comment: Again thank you very much for all your help. Yet, the graph still looks the same. Sorry for these beginner questions :)

Comment: I have included the data as well. Copy&pasting the complete code worked for me as expected.

Comment: It,s so strange. Even if I include the data you just provided, i get the graph looking like this - imgur.com/a/i90JrXZ. I wonder if its just one package I am missing. Well thanks anyway for all your help. Maybe I will be able to figure it out myself

Comment: please restart your session and load only the tidyverse package.

Comment: Ok I found the Problem :) Thank you so much. The Problem is the package Rmisc. It seems to clash with tidyverse